# SQL Schema Compare Not Creating CCDR scripts

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, schema-compare

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and trying to run a schema compare using the SQL tools.

The only difference between databases is the addition of a column for one table. When I go to generate the script, it is only giving me an `ALTER` statement, not a `CREATE-COPY-DROP-RENAME` script.

Is there a setting that enables schema compare to be able to do this?

Comment: You really *want* to perform all that extra work just to add a column to a table? Why?

Comment: Because the table has a lot of data and the new column is necessary.

Comment: Still don't understand why making a copy of the data - especially if there is a lot of it - is better? Why not take the alter statement and first make it nullable, then update the values in batches, then change it to not nullable?

Comment: Nevermind, I see what your saying. I had a complete blackout for a while.I just added the column with a default value.